# How to convert images to tabels?

Tags: tables

I am writing a research paper using LaTeX, so far I have to include 5 main comparison table in my work. I have converted manually the following image to a table but it is frustrating. Is there any way that I can convert the image records to table records in LaTeX?

[image]

and I am using the following code to generate the table:

```
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.95}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\begin{table}
\centering
 \vspace{-0.5cm}
\caption{List of top 20 Mutual Information Words for male (left) and female(right) class with the highest mutual information}
     \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
        \hline
        WORD & MI & PFC & PMC & F\_CT & M\_CT & WORD & MI & PFC & PMC & F\_CT & M\_CT \\ \hline
        users & 0.003 & 0.086 & 0.914 & 5 & 53 & love & 0.004 & 0.635 & 0.365 & 399 & 229 \\ \hline
        data    & 0.002 & 0.180 & 0.820 & 16 & 73 & mom & 0.004 & 0.785 & 0.215 & 117 & 32 \\ \hline
        similar & 0.002 & 0.219 & 0.781 & 25 & 89 & husband* & 0.004 & 0.796 & 0.204 & 109 & 28 \\ \hline
        its     & 0.002 & 0.371 & 0.629 & 251 & 425 & my & 0.003 & 0.557 & 0.443 & 1082 & 859 \\ \hline
        game*   & 0.002 & 0.309 & 0.691 & 80 & 179 & lunch* & 0.003 & 0.756 & 0.244  & 102  & 33 \\ \hline
        team*   & 0.002 & 0.284 & 0.716 & 55 & 139 & food* & 0.003 & 0.665 & 0.336  & 204  & 103 \\ \hline
        system* & 0.002 & 0.293 & 0.707 & 58 & 140 & lovely & 0.003 & 0.774 & 0.226  & 89  & 26 \\ \hline
        topps   & 0.002 & 0.000 & 1.000 & 0 & 21 & me & 0.003 & 0.557 & 0.443  & 873  & 694 \\ \hline
        video*  & 0.002 & 0.311 & 0.689 & 70 & 155 & meal* & 0.002 & 0.789 & 0.211  & 71  & 19 \\ \hline
        govern* & 0.002 & 0.256 & 0.744 & 32 & 93 & eating & 0.002 & 0.726 & 0.274  & 98  & 37 \\ \hline
        global* & 0.002 & 0.158 & 0.824 & 9 & 48 & her & 0.002 & 0.586 & 0.414  & 432  & 305 \\ \hline
        technologies & 0.002 & 0.042 & 0.958 & 1 & 23 & beaut* & 0.002 & 0.639 & 0.361  & 207  & 117 \\ \hline
        john    & 0.002 & 0.254 & 0.746 & 30 & 88 & baby* & 0.002 & 0.717 & 0.283  & 99  & 39 \\ \hline     
        model   & 0.002 & 0.227 & 0.773 & 20 & 68 & gorgeous* & 0.002 & 0.831 & 0.169  & 49  & 10 \\ \hline     
        web     & 0.002 & 0.273 & 0.727 & 36 & 96 & ladies & 0.002 & 0.846 & 0.154  & 44  & 8      \\ \hline
        bill    & 0.002 & 0.255 & 0.745 & 28 & 82 & cute* & 0.002 & 0.750 & 0.250  & 75  & 25      \\ \hline
        developer & 0.002 & 0.045 & 0.955 & 1 & 21 & fabulous* & 0.002 & 0.881 & 0.119  & 37  & 5      \\ \hline
        notion  & 0.001 & 0.077 & 0.923 & 2 & 24 & potato & 0.002 & 1.000 & 0.000  & 20  & 0      \\ \hline
        opera*  & 0.001 & 0.268 & 0.732 & 30 & 82 & kids* & 0.002 & 0.650 & 0.350  & 154  & 83      \\ \hline
        mike    & 0.001 & 0.176 & 0.824 & 9 & 42 & she & 0.002 & 0.579 & 0.421  & 398  & 289      \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \label{fig:top20list}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Are that really just images? png, jpg...? This would be off-topic then. You will have to search for some OCR software to do such thing. Apart from including those tables as images (you can stil put table caption and so on), there is no other way from TeX side but writing it all manually. I am sorry.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi ok then do you think is acceptable to let the tables as images.png in the LaTeX document instead of converting them to row tables?

Comment: personally, I would never do this as it is breaking the overall layout of your document. Would be a pity in my eyes. But of course, you will have to decide how much time you are able to spend on this work.

Comment: A) (as suggested) insert it as an image (which will ruin the overall glamour of the document) B) If it is some kind of data (Excel, OopenOffice, ...) maybe you can convert by OpenOffice and LaTeX-Export.

Comment: I'd try to get hold of a pdf version of the tables at least. You will still need to do some formatting by hand, but you can at least extract the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no solution in LaTeX for doing this.

You will have to search for some OCR software in order to get your data out of the image. You will have raw data then. Transferring this to a LaTeX-table could be done by other tools (search for excel-to-latex or similar).

The easiest solution would be to insert the images as `*.png` and to set it inside of a `table` environment.

But if you set those tables right, you will see that it is much nicer to have it as real LaTeX code.

```
% arara: pdflatex 

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{List of top 20 Mutual Information Words for male (left) and female (right) class with the highest mutual information}
    \begin{tabular}{%
            l
            S[table-format=1.3]
            S[table-format=1.3]
            S[table-format=1.3]
            S[table-format=2.0]
            S[table-format=3.0]
            @{\hskip 1cm}
            l
            S[table-format=1.3]
            S[table-format=1.3]
            S[table-format=1.3]
            S[table-format=4.0]
            S[table-format=3.0]
        }
        \toprule
        WORD & MI & PFC & PMC & F\_CT & M\_CT & WORD & MI & PFC & PMC & F\_CT & M\_CT \\ \midrule
        users & 0.003 & 0.086 & 0.914 & 5 & 53 & love & 0.004 & 0.635 & 0.365 & 399 & 229 \\ 
        data    & 0.002 & 0.180 & 0.820 & 16 & 73 & mom & 0.004 & 0.785 & 0.215 & 117 & 32 \\ 
        similar & 0.002 & 0.219 & 0.781 & 25 & 89 & husband* & 0.004 & 0.796 & 0.204 & 109 & 28 \\ 
        its     & 0.002 & 0.371 & 0.629 & 251 & 425 & my & 0.003 & 0.557 & 0.443 & 1082 & 859 \\ 
        game*   & 0.002 & 0.309 & 0.691 & 80 & 179 & lunch* & 0.003 & 0.756 & 0.244  & 102  & 33 \\ 
        team*   & 0.002 & 0.284 & 0.716 & 55 & 139 & food* & 0.003 & 0.665 & 0.336  & 204  & 103 \\ 
        system* & 0.002 & 0.293 & 0.707 & 58 & 140 & lovely & 0.003 & 0.774 & 0.226  & 89  & 26 \\ 
        topps   & 0.002 & 0.000 & 1.000 & 0 & 21 & me & 0.003 & 0.557 & 0.443  & 873  & 694 \\ 
        video*  & 0.002 & 0.311 & 0.689 & 70 & 155 & meal* & 0.002 & 0.789 & 0.211  & 71  & 19 \\ 
        govern* & 0.002 & 0.256 & 0.744 & 32 & 93 & eating & 0.002 & 0.726 & 0.274  & 98  & 37 \\ 
        global* & 0.002 & 0.158 & 0.824 & 9 & 48 & her & 0.002 & 0.586 & 0.414  & 432  & 305 \\ 
        technologies & 0.002 & 0.042 & 0.958 & 1 & 23 & beaut* & 0.002 & 0.639 & 0.361  & 207  & 117 \\ 
        john    & 0.002 & 0.254 & 0.746 & 30 & 88 & baby* & 0.002 & 0.717 & 0.283  & 99  & 39 \\      
        model   & 0.002 & 0.227 & 0.773 & 20 & 68 & gorgeous* & 0.002 & 0.831 & 0.169  & 49  & 10 \\      
        web     & 0.002 & 0.273 & 0.727 & 36 & 96 & ladies & 0.002 & 0.846 & 0.154  & 44  & 8      \\ 
        bill    & 0.002 & 0.255 & 0.745 & 28 & 82 & cute* & 0.002 & 0.750 & 0.250  & 75  & 25      \\ 
        developer & 0.002 & 0.045 & 0.955 & 1 & 21 & fabulous* & 0.002 & 0.881 & 0.119  & 37  & 5      \\ 
        notion  & 0.001 & 0.077 & 0.923 & 2 & 24 & potato & 0.002 & 1.000 & 0.000  & 20  & 0      \\ 
        opera*  & 0.001 & 0.268 & 0.732 & 30 & 82 & kids* & 0.002 & 0.650 & 0.350  & 154  & 83      \\ 
        mike    & 0.001 & 0.176 & 0.824 & 9 & 42 & she & 0.002 & 0.579 & 0.421  & 398  & 289      \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \label{fig:top20list}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thats Right, I just used an online OCR tool to convert the .png to .csv (https://convertio.co)

Comment: @Krebto Cool. I am happy that I could help you that easily. Have fun, TeXing!